# OCaml Heap Missing Nodes

Tags: ocaml, heap

I have defined a type heap:

```
type 'a heap = 
| Node of int * int * 'a heap * 'a heap
| Leaf;;
```

And the following functions:

```
let rank = function Leaf -> 0 | Node (r,_,_,_) -> r;;

let makeNode x a b = 
if rank a>= rank b then Node(rank b+1,x,a,b)
else Node (rank a+1,x,a,b);;

let rec meld  = function
|h,Leaf | Leaf,h -> h
| (Node(f,x,a1,b1)as h1),(Node(g,y,a2,b2)as h2) -> if  x >= y then makeNode x a1 (meld (b1, h2))
else makeNode y a2 (meld (h1, b2));;

let insert h x = meld ((Node(1,x,Leaf,Leaf)), h);;
```

However, when I insert a second node into the heap, the root disappears. How can I fix this:

```
let makeheap x = Node(1,x,Leaf,Leaf);;   
let myheap = makeheap 5;;
insert myheap 7;;
insert myheap 8;;
insert myheap 3;;
```

results in the following output:

```
val myheap : 'a heap = Node(1,5,Leaf,Leaf)
'a heap = Node(1,7,Leaf,Node(1,5,Leaf,Leaf))
'a heap = Node (1,8,Leaf,Node(1,5,Leaf,Leaf))
'a heap = Node(1,5,Leaf,Node(1,3,Leaf,Leaf))
```

Answer (score 2):

You're calling `insert` as if it's an imperative function. I.e., as if it's going to change some state. But your data structure is immutable. You have to think of `insert` as returning the new state.

You should read up on pure functional programming before going too much farther, I suspect.

The first few chapters of Okasaki's *Purely Functional Data Structures* explain things very well.

The answer to your immediate question is something like this:

```
# insert (insert myheap 7) 8;;
- : 'a heap = Node (1, 8, Leaf, Node (1, 7, Leaf, Node (1, 5, Leaf, Leaf)))
```